# custom no data label in nvd3 scatter chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to have custom message instead of the "No Data Available" message which is displayed. I am using nvd3 scatter / bubble chart. I came across a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458236/nvd3-showing-empty-chart-instead-of-nodata-message)

```
data2 = [ 
  { 
  "key" : "A key" , 
  "values" : [[]]
  }
];
```

but I want to change the message. I looked at the source scatter.js but did not find "No Data Available" message. Do I need to modify another source file? How can I do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/c6c00d4a349a45810981b9c45a17c1420d4fa2ea/src/models/scatterChart.js), it seems that you can set the message using `.noData()`:

```
chart.noData("Nothing to see here.");
```

Comment: Is there any way we can change the color as well ?

Comment: Of the string? You can select the element and change it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried this but its not taking color value, however text-decoration works fine. text.nvd3.nv-noData{
 color:"yellow";
 text-decoration: underline;
}

Comment: You might want to post a separate question about this.

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to use the [Angular NVD3 wrapper](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/), the way to set the custom message is through chart options, simply:

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
      ...
      noData: 'Your custom message',
      ...
    }
  };
```

I have prepared a simple demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hORaQh?p=preview